# Couting html tags with Ruby style (inject, blocks, each...)

Tags: ruby

I want to count the number of ocurrences of several html tags in a certain page. I could do it the classic way but I am trying to do it the Ruby way.

This is what I did, but instead of adding up every partial count, it is creating a string with the list's elements:

```
tags = [ '<img>', '<script>', '<applet>', '<video>', '<audio>' ]
weight = tags.each { |tag| web.to_s.scan(/#{tag}/).length }.inject(:+)
```

Any tips?

**edit:**

```
def browse startpage, depth, block
    if depth > 0
        begin 
            web = open(startpage).read
            block.call startpage, web
        rescue
            return
        end
        links = URI.extract(web)
        links.each { |link| browse link, depth-1, block } 
    end
end

browse("https://www.youtube.com/", 2, lambda { |page_name, web|
    tags = [ '<img>', '<script>', '<applet>', '<video>', '<audio>' ]
    web.force_encoding 'utf-8'
    parsed_string = Nokogiri::HTML(web)
    weight = tags.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |tag, hash|
      occurrences = parsed_string.xpath("//#{tag.gsub(/[<>]/, '')}").length
      hash[tag] = occurrences
    end
    puts "Page weight for #{web.base_uri} = #{weight}"
})
```

Comment: Just replace `each` with `map`

Comment: Revemo the rescue block along with the return, it makes debugging impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to solve your problem:

```
web = "<audio> <audio> <video>" # I guess 'web' is other than a string in your example, so the need for to_s below
tags = [ '<img>', '<script>', '<applet>', '<video>', '<audio>' ]

tag_occurrences = tags.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |tag, hash|
  occurrences = web.to_s.scan(/#{tag}/).length
  hash[tag] = occurrences
end

p tag_occurrences #=> {"<img>"=>0, "<script>"=>0, "<applet>"=>0, "<video>"=>1, "<audio>"=>2}
```

It's not recommended you use regular expressions to match tags, though. A much better way is to use something like Nokogiri to count the tags:

```
require 'nokogiri'
web = "<audio> <audio> <video>" 
parsed_string = Nokogiri::HTML(web.to_s) #using to_s because I'm assuming web isn't an actual string in your code
tags = [ '<img>', '<script>', '<applet>', '<video>', '<audio>' ]

tag_occurrences = tags.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |tag, hash|
  occurrences = parsed_string.xpath("//#{tag.gsub(/[<>]/, '')}").length
  hash[tag] = occurrences
end

p tag_occurrences #=> {"<img>"=>0, "<script>"=>0, "<applet>"=>0, "<video>"=>1, "<audio>"=>2}
```

Regarding your comment, I've used this on YouTube (using my second snippet of code to process the data) and got:

```
require 'open-uri'
web = open('http://youtube.com').read
# the code above to parse web using Nokogiri
p tag_occurrences #=> {"<img>"=>151, "<script>"=>13, "<applet>"=>0, "<video>"=>0, "<audio>"=>0}
```

Comment: I am getting 0 tags counted with both methods. The page I am using is youtube. What is wrong?

Comment: What do you use to obtain the data from YouTube?

Comment: Please see my updated answer on your YouTube remark.

Comment: I can't manage to figure this out. Look at the code I updated in my original post.

Comment: This site is not for refactoring your code. You can do that on yourself. For a start, remove the 'rescue' clause all together because it will make debuggin impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I would [`traverse`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#traverse-instance_method) the document once, counting the node names:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('https://www.youtube.com/'))
tags_count = Hash.new(0)
doc.traverse { |node| tags_count[node.name] += 1 }
tags_count
#=> {"html"=>2, "#cdata-section"=>12, "script"=>15, "text"=>7958, "link"=>11, "title"=>1, "meta"=>4, "comment"=>18, "head"=>1, "div"=>1152, "input"=>2, "form"=>2, "img"=>135, "span"=>2878, "a"=>397, "button"=>434, "label"=>1, "li"=>740, "ul"=>265, "hr"=>3, "h3"=>117, "p"=>48, "br"=>3, "strong"=>2, "ol"=>1, "h2"=>26, "b"=>5, "body"=>1, "document"=>1}
```